# react-native how to put icon left of full width button

Tags: react-native, native-base

Using [NativeBase](https://docs.nativebase.io/button) v3 library, There is leftIcon props, but it place icon near of title in center I need icon very left of the button, here is my component;

```
<Button
              width="full"
              primary
              onPress={() => {}}
              leftIcon={<Icon name="check" size={12} color="white" />}
            >
              <Text style={{color: 'white'}}> Checkout </Text>
            </Button>
```

need to put icon as seem in pic below;

[image]

And, do you know whats name of the icon at right? :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing the as prop on your passed icon. And i think the placement can be changed if you add a style prop to the icon
try:

```
leftIcon={<Icon as={Ionicons} name="check" size={12} color="white" style={{alignSelf: 'flex-start'}} />}
```

And i think the icons on the right of your image is just three chevron-right with decreasing opacity